# Three.js finding vertices of buffergeometry after .fromGeometry();

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, vertex, buffer-geometry

How do I find vertices positions of a mesh after I used `.fromGeometry();` code? I created a buffergeometry from a geomtery that I used for a mesh. Here is an example.

```
var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var buffgeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
buffgeom.fromGeometry(geom);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(buffgeom, mat);

geometryvertices.vertices = buffgeom.vertices;
```

The `geometryvertices.vertices = buffgeom.vertices;` code doesn't work for `buffgeom`. How do I find vertices positions of `buffgeom`? Can somebody please help?

After that I want to push the vertices of a geometry into `THREE.Vector3`. This is how it worked with a geometry.

```
geom.vertices.push(Vector3);
```

And it doesn't work with a buffergeometry.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tempGeo = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(myMesh.geometry);
for (var i= 0; i< tempGeo.vertices.length; i++) {
  var pos = tempGeo.vertices[i].applyMatrix4(myMesh.matrix);
}
```